# Is there a FNP problem that's NP-hard but not FNP-hard?

Tags: np-hardness, reductions, search-problem

For the [reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction), choose a class C such that [it's clear what [F](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp)C means]

and FC is not known to be able to solve the [satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) search problem,

and assume that FC indeed can't solve that search problem.

With the following definitions of hardness for [FNP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp) problems R,

NP-hard ​ ​ - ​ ​ The [corresponding decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem) is NP-hard (with respect to C reductions).

FNP-hard ​ ​ - ​ ​ There is a C reduction f from [satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) to the corresponding decision problem

and a function g in FC such that for all instances x of the satisfiability problem,

for all strings y, if ​ f(x) R y ​ then g(x,y) is a satisfying assignment to x.

is there a FNP problem that's NP-hard but not FNP-hard?

Comment: I am not sure about your notion of FNP-hardness. By standard definition, The search version of Satisfiability is FNP-complete. Hence, the NP-hardness of a decision problem implies the FNP-hardness of the corresponding search problem.

Comment: "The search version of Satisfiability is" also FNP-complete by my definition. ​ _What is_ the standard definition of FNP-hardness? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: See this: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1126/495 and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNP_(complexity). "the FNP version of every NP-complete problem is NP-hard".

Comment: Those two links only show _NP_-hardness, not _FNP_-hardness. ​ (I also don't see a definition of the latter concept in either of those links.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Aha, I got you. Under Karp reduction it is unknown. But, if you consider ASP-reductions (which require a bijection between solutions spaces of the two problems) then the answer is No to your question.

Comment: I'm not restricting to ASP reductions (unless your description is much stronger than their actual definition. ​ For example, SAT can easily have a unique solution, but [NAE-SAT](http://blog.geomblog.org/2008/03/joys-of-nae-sat.html) is NP-hard and can only have an even number of solutions.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Here you find the definition of ASP reductions. http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yato/data2/MasterThesis.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure, but this paper may be relevant http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2014/110/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to argue that the answer is probably "Yes", i.e.,

there probably are FNP problems that are NP-hard but not FNP-hard.

Warmup: ​ With respect to polynomially-closed reduction classes that can't solve all of FNPSPACE, FNPSPACE-hardness is different from NPSPACE-hardness.

Proof: ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Let R be the relation given by xRy if and only if [x$\in$QBF$\hspace{.02 in}$ and y is the empty string].

QBF [$\in$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula#Solving) PSPACE-complete [$=$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem) NPSPACE-complete , ​ so R is in FNPSPACE and NPSPACE-hard.

Let f and g form an arbitrary reduction from an arbitrary

relation S to R, and let x be an arbitrary instance of S.

x has an S-witness ​ $\implies$ ​ f(x) has an R-witness ​ $\implies$

f(x) R empty_string ​ $\implies$ ​ x S g(x,empty_string) ​ .

In other words, an arbitrary reduction from a search problem to R can be used

to solve the search problem. ​ ​ ​ Therefore R is not FNPSPACE-hard with respect

to polynomially-closed reduction classes that can't solve all of FNPSPACE.

Cryptographic Assumptions and sub-P reductions:

For each positive integer j, let R<sub>$\hspace{.02 in}$j</sub> be the relation given by ​ x R (C,v) ​ if and only if C is a [circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit)

and x is a [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)-[SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) instace and ​ size(C) ≤ (number_of_variables_in_(x))<sup>$\hspace{.03 in}$j</sup> ​ and C(v) [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability) x. ​ ​ ​ Obviously, each R<sub>$\hspace{.02 in}$j</sub> is in FNP and NP-hard. ​ ​ ​ If they are all FNP-hard under non-uniform [parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29) reductions, then there can't even be a version of [time-lock puzzles](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/RivestShamirWagner-timelock.pdf) against

non-uniform adversaries that is otherwise very weak, namely, ones in which [the size of the

puzzle can be polynomial in the time for an honest user to solve it] and [there is no restriction

on the resources needed to create the puzzle] and [security only needs to hold infinitely often]. ​ Furthermore, if there are efficiently-computable functions that are [one-way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) against probabilistic

parallel adversaries then one can replace both instances of "non-uniform" with "probabilistic". 

Probabilistic Polynomial-Time Reductions and handwaving:

(This is essentially tautological, but) If all NP-hard FNP problems are FNP-hard, then all

[proof systems](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sabhar/publications/iaspcmi-proofcomplexity00.pdf) for SAT are "somewhat constructive", in the sense that any original instance can

be efficiently turned an equisatisfiable instance so that one will be able to go from any proof of

satisfiability of the equisatisfiable instance to a satisfying assignment of the original instance.

[Non-interactive zaps](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/PUBLIC/73.pdf) are certainly not obviously "somewhat constructive" in that sense.